# Which is better: "it may happen that..." or "may happen that..."?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Which sentence is better in a text:

> "It may happen that some people believe"
>   or
>   "May happen that some people believe"

Comment: If you had taken the Introductory Tour you would see that this site is for people interested in the English Language and is not a proof-reading servicce for non-native speakers. You might look at SE English Language Learners, but please read the instructions for that site to make sure your question is posed in a suitable manner.

Answer (score 3):

Except in certain particular contexts (such as imperatives, and colloquial conversation) English always requires a subject to be expressed: that is precisely why [expletive 'it'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) is used.

So, in most contexts "May happen that ... " at the start of a sentence is not grammatical.